# How to find a unique article id/page id for an HTML page using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to find a unique article ID/page ID associated with each HTML page. However, the problem is for each HTML page the article id is in different format. For example, articleId, article-id, articleID, value, netID etc.
For most HTML page, the article id can be found in the script tag. This is how it text inside script tag looks:

> 

```html
<script type="text/javascript">var lf_config = [{"collectionMeta":"eyJ0eXAiOiJqd3QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0aXRsZSI6IkN1dCBGYXQgRmFzdCYjODIzMDthbmQgSGF2ZSBGdW4gRG9pbmcgSXQhIiwidXJsIjoiaHR0cHM6XC9cL2Jsb29kcHJlc3N1cmVzb2x1dGlvbi5jb21cL2N1dC1mYXQtZmFzdC1mdW5cLyIsInRhZ3MiOiIiLCJjaGVja3N1bSI6IjIxODcxZjdmYTVkZTcwNjQ2NDAyNzk2YjFjMDFiZTE2IiwiYXJ0aWNsZUlkIjoxMTMzfQ.A4dXaOb2eIKk2OiANm0USozRiof21OKzQUjvy6fymgg",
"checksum":"21871f7fa5de70646402796b1c01be16",
"siteId":"339299",
"articleId":1133,"strings":"","el":"livefyre-comments"}];var conv = fyre.conv.load({}, lf_config);</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var wpcf7 = {"apiSettings":{"root":"https:\/\/bloodpressuresolution.com\/wp-json\/contact-form-7\/v1","namespace":"contact-form-7\/v1"},"recaptcha":{"messages":{"empty":"Please verify that you are not a robot."}}};
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

This is the code I tried but it doesn't yield any output yet. The list new_link has URLs of each HTML page. I think the regex is fine, but i am unable to parse the text inside  tag and search for the regex. I want to store the article id and its value ultimately as my output.  Kindly help me to figure out how I can find unique article ids from each HTML page.

````
for i in new_link:
    new_req = requests.get(i, headers=hdr)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(new_req.text, "html.parser")
    scripts = soup.findAll("script", attrs={"type" : "text/javascript"})
    for j in scripts:
        temp = re.findall(pattern, str(j))
        print(temp)```
````

Answer (score 0):

if you want to find en element or object  by id

```
div = soup.find(id="articlebody")
```

Comment: By id, I am not referring to the attribute id. In this case, the article id is unique to each HTML page.